# failed to open stream: No such file or directory (but files are in the correct location)

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2, cron, themes

I receive hundreds of emails every day error from my WP theme. I do not know why, and even the developer cannot give me some advice, everything seems okay, but obviously it is not. This is the error I get on my postfix mail service:

```
Return-Path: <ubuntu@mysite.org>
X-Original-To: ubuntu
Delivered-To: ubuntu@mysite.org
Received: by mysite.org (Postfix, from userid 1000)
        id C4E78E9B7; Fri, 26 Dec 2014 11:30:01 +0000 (UTC)
From: root@mysite.org (Cron Daemon)
To: ubuntu@mysite.org
Subject: Cron <ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-250> php -q /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/cron.php
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ubuntu>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=ubuntu>
Message-Id: <20141226113001.C4E78E9B7@mysite.org>
Date: Fri, 26 Dec 2014 11:30:01 +0000 (UTC)
X-IMAPbase: 1419593539 75
Status: O
X-UID: 74

PHP Warning:  require(../../../wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/cron.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../../../wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/cron.php on line 2
?
```

the files are in the correct position, this is the file cron.php:

```
<?php
require '../../../wp-load.php';
echo file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri().'/scheduler.php');
?>
```

this is the scheduler.php file:

```
<?php
//PLEASE do NOT move me around. I get cranky when I get moved around
//get the wp-load in for the wordpress functions
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
//now try calling template function
CheckFunction();
?>
```

I'm in a WP multisite environment, the wp-load.php is located in "html" folder, it's in the correct location, so why this happen?

Comment: so when you write require `'../../../wp-load.php';` that is the correct location of wp-load.php RELATIVE to scheduler.php?

Comment: @Todd wp-load.php is located in /var/www/html; instead cron.php and scheduler.php are located in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/mytheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must not be finding the file. Try changing cron.php to a more usuable require:

```
<?php
// Require WP
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';
// Run code
```

EDIT:

You can also try a less portable solution that'll work for this server specifically:

```
<?php
// Require WP
require '/var/www/html/wp-load.php';
```

If this still doesn't work, it might be a permission issue. Make sure the file permission is 644.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the try...I got the same error, the only  difference is this "Failed opening required '/wp-load.php'"

Comment: I was so skeptical about the use of '/var/www/html/wp-load.php' ...incredible it works! But why others solutions before (that seemed correct) not??

Comment: @drhouse It's most likely because when PHP runs from the CLI for the CRON job, it's root directory is different than when browsing to the site. Because of this, the relative paths aren't correct for CLI.